# IConnectableObservables in Rx

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Can someone explain the differences between an Observable and a ConnectableObservable?  The Rx Extensions documentation is very sparse and I don't understand in what cases the ConnectableObservable is useful.

This class is used in the Replay/Prune methods.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`IConnectableObservable` represents a *pending* hot observable that can be shared with multiple subscribers. Calling `IConnectableObservable.Connect()` causes the change to hot (subscribes to the cold source observable)

**Long answer:**

A *cold observable* (like `Observable.Range`) replays the sequence for each subscriber. It's analagous to a stopwatch, where every subscriber is given their own stopwatch. The subscriber starts the stopwatch by subscribing, and the stopwatch stops (and resets) once the observer stops observing.

A *hot observable* shares the sequence between all subscribers. It's analagous to there being one stopwatch and all subscribers are given the same time readout, regardless of when they started watching.

`IObservable.Publish` converts a cold observable into a hot observable, but returns an `IConnectableObservable`. This enables subscribers to subscribe to the (single) stopwatch before it starts. Calling `IConnectableObservable.Connect()` starts the stopwatch. Disposing the `Connect()` return value stops the stopwatch.

It's worth noting that some observable sources are hot by nature. For example, mouse events can fire regardless of whether we are subscribed to them. All a connectable observable would do in this scenario is a share a single event subscription.