# why is the second item in these RxJS.Observable sequences getting skipped?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have the following RxJS code:

```
let items = Observable.of({
  val: "one",
  type: "string"
}, {
  val: "five",
  type: "string"
}, {
  val: 2,
  type: "integer"
}, {
  val: 10,
  type: "integer"
}, {
  val: 20,
  type: "integer"
});

items
  .groupBy(x => x.type)
  .subscribe(obs => {
    let head = obs.first();
    let tail = obs.skip(1);
    head
      .do(x => console.log('head == ', x))
      .concat(tail)
      .do(x => console.log('tail == ', x))
      .subscribe(x => console.log('sub == ', x));

  });
```

Here's the output:

```
head ==  Object {val: "one", type: "string"}
tail ==  Object {val: "one", type: "string"}
sub ==  Object {val: "one", type: "string"}

head ==  Object {val: 2, type: "integer"}
tail ==  Object {val: 2, type: "integer"}
sub ==  Object {val: 2, type: "integer"}
tail ==  Object {val: 20, type: "integer"}
sub ==  Object {val: 20, type: "integer"}
```

Why is the second item not getting emitted?

Here's a [Plunk that demonstrates my problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/aqthwXUfH6oTwTKp9M56?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to explain what is happening here, but there is no magic so let's see if I can find the words (see thereafter). Following that lengthy explanation is a proposed workaround.

Let's say `observer` is `obs => {    let head = obs.first();....`

- `Observable.of(...)` is a cold observable which will emit one by one the items... whenever an observer will subscribe (definition of cold observable).
- `groupBy` is also a cold observable, but it creates hot observables which are your type groups. That means that when a items comes in, it is associated to a group observable and immediately emitted to whatever observer were there (definition of hot observable). If no observer, then the value is lost.
- Your first `subscribe(observer)` leads to the following :

  - `observer` subscribes to `groupBy` which subscribes to `Observable.of` which hence emit the first item from items (`val: "one", type: "string"`). Let-s call it `item_string_1`.
  - `groupBy` creates the first group hot observable (call it `obs_string`), emits it to `observer` THEN emits the first item on that first group.
  - when `obs_string` is emitted, `observer` is executed (remember observers are executed every time their related observable emits). That means that 
    `item_string_1` will be emitted AFTER `observer` is executed.
  - First observer execution : Your `subscribe` in the observer leads to the following:

    - subscription of `observer2` (`x => console.log('sub == ', x)`) to `concat(tail)`
    - `concat(tail)` subscribes immediately to `head` and DOES NOT subscribe to `tail` in this moment. It will subscribe to it only when `head` has completed. That's one of the key points.
    - `head` leads to subscription to `first` which leads to subscription to `obs`, which leads to... nothing as no value has been emitted by `obs`.
    - end of observer execution
  - then `item_string_1` is emitted on `obs_string`. That leads to :

    - `head` emitting `item_string_1`, `concat(tail)` emitting `item_string1` and all your `console.log` showing `Object {val: "one", type: "string"}`.
    - `head` completes
  - then `item_string_2` is emitted on `obs_string`. That leads to :

    - `concat(tail)` subscribes to `tail` which subscribes to `skip(1)` which subscribes to `obs` (which is `obs_string` for the moment). That means that `concat(tail)` emits... nothing. It skips the first value of `obs`, first value counted from the moment it subscribed. That first value is `item_string_2` which is the second value emitted. Conclusion : your second value is NEVER emitted.
  - then `item_integer_1` is emitted. Same behaviour as `item_string_1`
  - then `item_integer_2` is emitted. Same behaviour as `item_string_2` (skipped)
  - then `item_integer_3` is emitted. Now the `skip(1)` emits `val: 20, type: "integer"` which makes it way to the messages in `console.log`

Proposed workaround:

Not sure if I understand well, but if you want to do something specific depending on the index of the element, just use `map(selector(value, index))` as follows :

```
items
  .groupBy(x => x.type)
  .subscribe(obs => obs.map(function(value, index){
                               return index == 0 ? process_first(value)
                                                 : process_others(value)
                            })
                       .subscribe(x => console.log('sub == ', x))
```

Comment: Thanks for putting so much detail into this fantastic answer! I'm still a little unclear on a few things: 1) when `item_string_1` is emitted, could you elaborate on why `concat(tail)` emits `item_string_1`? 2) if i understand you correctly, the `obs` observer can be executed when a) the hot observer group (eg., `obs_string`) gets emitted, or a value from that group is emitted (`item_string_1`). How do I tell when `obs` will be `a` or `b`? I'm accepting your answer now, because your suggestion did help although I went with `concatMap` instead.

Comment: 1) The `obs1.concat(obs2)` observable will subscribe to `obs1`, emit the values from `obs1` till `obs1` completes, and then subscribe to `obs2` and emits the values from obs2. So as `obs1` (`head` here) emits `item_string_1 ` that's what the `concat` will emit

Comment: 2) No, `obs` is not an observer. An observer is a function, `obs` is an observable. Here `obs.subscribe(observer)` entails that the observer function will be executed every time obs emits a value. There are not two cases, only one. Here, `obs_string` leads to `observer` execution, the `item_string_1` is emitted on `obs_string` and leads to the execution of any observer that have subscribed to `obs_string`, here at the end of the chain it leads to executing the `console.log`

Comment: For the first and second items, `obs` is `obs_to_string`. For third, fourth and fifth item, `obs` is `obs_to_integer`. The complete chain of execution would be in all cases `obs->first->head->concat->console.log`

Comment: Lastly, `concatMap` also gives you access to inner and outer index information, so that can help achieve your goal too. Cf https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/concatmap.md

Comment: *typo in my comment starting with `For the first and second items`. Replace `obs->...` by `obs->first->concat->console.log`. I haven't included the `do` but of course they are also traversed.

Comment: I'm a little slow with rx programming, so please forgive me for not understanding. In your main answer you say: "groupBy creates the first group hot observable (call it obs_string), emits it to observer THEN emits the first item on that first group." let's just talk about those emissions. when the first group observable is emitted, does that get passed to the observer, THEN the first element of the `items` Observable gets emitted to the same observer?

Comment: is there a way to do a line-by-line walkthrough of what happens on each `observer` execution? i think seeing that for myself might help me understand what's really going on.

Comment: No problem, I found it hard too in my beginnings. There really are two different things happening. The first group observable is emitted and the observer is executed with that first group observable as a parameter (the observer is `obs => {let head... subscribe(observer2)`). At that time all that does is subscribing `observer2` to an observable derived from `obs` (chain is `obs->first->concat`). Then the first item is emitted by the first group observable. That first item goes down the chain `obs->first->concat` and executes `observer2` and the log message ends up printed.

Comment: To trace what is happening, do what you already did, put a `do` after every operator you use and observe what gets out. I hope to find some time tomorrow and draw you a marble. A drawing should be more efficient at explaining

Comment: I added more `do` statements to my original [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/aqthwXUfH6oTwTKp9M56?p=preview). I only get `in obs` printed once, so the `groupBy` observable only emits once -- the first group observable. Where is the first item (`item_string_1`) emitted?

Comment: The groupBy emits one observable (there is only one group). THAT observable emits the items. You subscribed indirectly to that observable with your `console.log` observer. Ok I'll do a drawing later. You can go ahead and review the marbles here : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html

Comment: ah, ok. I think I'm getting closer to understanding this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you get a chance to make that drawing you mentioned? I hope you didn't misinterpret "getting closer to understanding" from my previous comment to mean I wouldn't like to see that drawing.

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators/34669444#34669444 (see addition). About the group thing, I could not do better than the marbles, I am afraid.