# Rx (JS): how to update subscriptions in flatMap stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, cyclejs

I have a state$ stream that constains messages$s which is array of messages$ stream. State$ is updated and new messages$ appear.

I want subscriber to handle messages from all messages$ in one sinle stream an I want this this stream contain only correct events.

I try to flatMap merged messages$ every time, but got the problem that old messages$s (which where in previous states$ values) are subsribed multiple timed.

How do I solve this?

`let allMessages$ = state$.flatMap(s => {
      return Observable.merge(s.messages$s)
    }
  )
 allMessages$.subscribe((x)=>{
    console.log('message', x)
    // message from single message$ appear multiple times
  })`

The problem is that after state$ is updated (with items pushed) old one became to be subscribed multiple times.

`state$              --s(1)---------s(2)----
message$s[0].       --m1----m2-----------m4--
message$s[1]        ---------------m3--------
allMessages$        --m1----m2-----m3----m4
                                   m1    m4`

s(1) - when state has 1 message$, s(2) when second message$ is added
So allMessages$ fire with messages from item1.

What i want is:

`state$              --s(1)---------s(2)-----
message$s[0]        --m1----m2-----------m4--
message$s[1]        ---------------m3--------
allMessages$        --m1----m2-----m3----m4`

This fildle shows the situation simplified:
http://jsfiddle.net/8jFJH/797/

Comment: hard to understand what you say. Best is to give an example of input, expected output, and actual output, and explain the discrepancy (as if you would write a test for your function basically). My best bet is that you have to use `flatMapLatest` instead of `flatMap` but hard to say without understanding the specifications of your function.

Comment: Ok tried to draw. The problem is that  resulting sream recieves multiple events from from the same streams.

Comment: Actually I managed to do this adding `distinct()` not sure if its correct solution as I'm new to RxJs.

Comment: does that mean your problem is solved?

Comment: I would like to get the confirmation that it is correct solution, or get another one.

Comment: `distinct` allow you to not repeat twice the same value in your stream. So if by any chance, m4 = m1 you won't see that m4 in your stream. So I guess `distinct` is not what you need. Your `message$` source is hot or cold?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100710/discussion-between-whitecolor-and-user3743222).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your simplified situation, these are the subscriptions sequences (you can review the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators) for explanation of hot vs. cold observables, and understanding of subscription flows):

- emission of `state1`

  - subscription to `typing$`
- emission of `state2`

  - subscription to `typing$`
  - subscription to `typing2$`

Because you use `flatMap`, you have three subscriptions at the same time. If you use `flatMapLatest` here is what happens :

- emission of `state1`

  - subscription to `typing$`
- emission of `state2`

  - 'unsubscription' (is that even english language) from previous stream emitted in `flatMapLatest` i.e. `Rx.Observable.merge(state.items)` i.e. `typing$`
  - subscription to `typing$`
  - subscription to `typing2$`

So try replacing `flatMap` by `flatMapLatest` and let me know if that solves the problem.

Another way to solve this could also to work with a stream of state changes instead of with the whole state (kind of what redux does for react).

Comment: Yes it solves) thank you very much. As Well have to add share() to startWith.

Comment: Redux way is not functional actually. But if based on state changes, how to remove existing subscrptions (when item is removed from state)?

Comment: yes, that's why the 'kind of'. You're right, removing might complicate too much in this case. Basically to remove you need to terminate a given stream. You can do that by appending a `takeUntil` somewhere, but then you have to manage a stream terminator for each stream. So if there is no performance penalty, it could be better to do the current way.