# How to resume RxJs Observable Interval on Error

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am merging two Observables.
The first one gets the current temperature on init.
The second one polls at a certain interval the API.
If the Api call fails, then the Observable interval is not resumed.

How could I resume it?

```
getCurrentTemp(): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.get(this.environmentService.getTemperatureUrl())
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .switchMap(() => res.temp);
  }

  pollCurrentTemperature(): Subscription {
    const temp$ = this.getCurrentTemp();
    const tempInterval$ = Observable
      .interval(3000)
      .flatMap(() => this.getCurrentTemp());

    return temp$
      .take(1)
      .merge(tempInterval$)
      .subscribe((temp: number) => {
        console.log('temp', temp);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log('error', err);
        // When the api fails my interval does not resume. How can I retry it?
      });
  }
```

Any ideas? Ty

Comment: maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34999441/2829204

Comment: You want the interval to continue from the last `index` that didn't fail?

Answer (score 1):

Use [catch](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html).

> Catch: recover from an onError notification by continuing the sequence without error

```
getCurrentTemp(): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.get(this.environmentService.getTemperatureUrl())
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch(error => {
          console.log('Error occured');
          return Observable.empty();
       });
      .switchMap(() => res.temp);
}
```

It will catch the error and silently return an [empty](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/empty-never-throw.html) observable in its place. In effect, the switchmap will skip over the failed api call silently as it will not emit for the empty observable.

Of course, you could have an alternate behaviour on error, but you need to catch it to avoid the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Using the http status codes you can retrieve an observable only if its a 200 let's say:

```js
 getCurrentTemp(): Observable<number> {
    return Observable.from(
      [
        { value: 1, status: 200 },
        { value: 2, status: 200 },
        { value: 3, status: 200 },
        { value: 4, status: 200 },
        { value: 5, status: 200 },
        { value: 6, status: 400 }])
      .switchMap((x: any) => {
        if (x.status === 200) {
          return Observable.of(x.value);
        }
        return Observable.onErrorResumeNext();
      });
  }

  pollCurrentTemperature(): Subscription {
    const temp$ = this.getCurrentTemp();
    const tempInterval$ = Observable
      .interval(3000)
      .flatMap(() => this.getCurrentTemp());

    return temp$
      .take(1)
      .merge(tempInterval$)
      .subscribe((temp: number) => {
        console.log('temp', temp);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log('error', err);
        // When the api fails my interval does not resume. How can I retry it?
      });
  }
```

The important bit is this **return Observable.onErrorResumeNext();**