# Angular Observable destroy with takeUntil: What happens when .next() is missing in ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, unsubscribe

In an Angular 7 Component, I use the RxJS takeUntil() to properly unsubscribe on observable subscriptions.

- What happens when the `this.destroy$.next()` is missing in the method `ngOnDestroy` (see sample below)? Will it still unsubscribe properly?
- What happens when the `this.destroy$.complete()` is missing in the method `ngOnDestroy` (see sample below)? Will it still unsubscribe properly?
- Is there any way to enforce that pattern with takeUntil() to unsubscribe is properly used (e.g. tslint rule, npm package)?

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-flights',
    templateUrl: './flights.component.html'
})
export class FlightsComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    private readonly destroy$ = new Subject();

    public flights: FlightModel[];

    constructor(private readonly flightService: FlightService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.flightService.getAll()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
            .subscribe(flights => this.flights = flights);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850409/rxjs-subject-next-after-complete

Comment: Use https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `takeUntil` takes next as emission. If only `complete()` called it won't unsubscribe

try this out:

```
const a=new Subject();
interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(a)).subscribe(console.log);
timer(3000).subscribe(_=>a.complete())
```

2. `this.destroy$` is still in the memory and won't get garbage collected
3. Not that i am aware of

Please also take a look here to avoid memory leak when using `takeUntil`.

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef

Personally I prefer explicit `unsubscribe` upon destroy.

Comment: #2 is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007118/do-i-need-to-complete-takeuntil-subject-inside-ngondestroy for why.

Comment: We are just talking about when subject can be totally become stale and garbage collected, and also imagine if this component is an application wrapper and exist throughout all pages.

Comment: OP specifically asked about calling it in ngOnDestroy (component is being removed) with a clear code example that doesn't show any other reference to `this.destroy$`. Therefore that answer can be misleading.

Comment: in that case i have overlooked the actual use case scenario, but i would still suggest to add .complete() ` as a good practice. if this subject is being subscribed by other component or service  there will still be memory leak even if component is removed from my understanding.

Comment: Right. But again there's no sign of outside reference in OP's example, and it's not a typical case with this approach. I would still suggest editing the answer and clarifying the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler approach:

```
private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

...

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: You may not need the type declaration on the Subject

Answer (score 1):

`this.destroy$.next()` triggers the Subject which triggers the `takeUntil` operator which completes the `flightService.getAll()` subscription.

`this.destroy$.complete()` completes the `destroy$` Subject when component is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use **takeWhile** instead of **takeUntil**.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-flights',
    templateUrl: './flights.component.html'
})
export class FlightsComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    private readonly destroy$ = new Subject();
    alive = true;
    public flights: FlightModel[];

    constructor(private readonly flightService: FlightService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.flightService.getAll()
            .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
            .subscribe(flights => this.flights = flights);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.alive = false;
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why prefer takeWhile here? Not sure this inversion to the accepted answer gives much of an additional benefit. The destroy$ property of your class is superfluous too