# Reconnecting a WebSocket with a shared RxJS observable

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs

I have an observable like this:

```
const records$ =
    Rx.DOM.fromWebSocket('ws://192.168.2.4:9001/feed/', null)
    .map(ev => parseRecord(ev.data))
    .share();
```

I have many subscribers. When the connection is lost, all subscribers unsubscribe:

```
let records$Subscription;
records$Subscription = records$.subscribe(
    record => { ... },
    error => records$Subscription.dispose()
);
```

I verified that the call to `dispose` is indeed being made once for every subscription. Therefore, the `share` refcount has reached zero.

However, when I now subscribe to `records$` again, no new WebSocket connection is set up. When I remove the call to `share`, however, it *is*. How come this doesn't work as expected with `share`?

Comment: which version of Rxjs are you using?

Comment: @user3743222 RxJS v4.1.0 and RxJS-DOM v7.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in rxjs v5, `share` does allow you to reconnect but not in Rxjs v4.

In Rxjs 4, `share` is bascially `multicast.refCount` and once the subject used for the multicast is completed, it cannot be reused (per Rxjs grammar rules, have a look at [What are the semantics of different RxJS subjects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849873/what-are-the-semantics-of-different-rxjs-subjects/34860777#34860777) too), leading to the behaviour you observed.

In Rxjs 5, it uses a subject factory (something like `multicast(() => new Rx.Suject().refCount())`), so a subject is recreated when necessary.

See issues [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/678) and [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1363) for more details.

In short, if you can't do with the current behavior, you can switch to the v5 (note that it is still in beta and there are some breaking changes).