# RxJS 5: Can I create a `BehaviorObservable`?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, behaviorsubject

I'm creating a class for my app that keeps an internal [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html). Is there a way I can expose a corresponding '`BehaviorObservable`', which pipes through the values of the subject, but only has the 'read-only' stuff of the [`Observable`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) interface? The `.next()`, `.error()` and `.complete()` methods should only be available internally.

It's not just a matter (I believe) of using [`Observable.create()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribe) to pipe the subject's values through. Users of my API should `.subscribe()` to the exposed observable, and then immediately get a callback for the stored current value.

I may be able to hack something together, but I'm sure I'm just missing something that RxJS can already do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance looking for the `.asObservable()` method - which existed in Rxjs v4. Don't know if that is still the case in Rxjs v5 though.

According to [this](http://www.ceus-now.com/how-to-transform-a-subject-into-an-observable-in-rxjs-5/), the method should have been included in release 5.0.0-beta.2. Also I quote here their work-around if the functionality is not there :

> You can get the same functionality by creating an observable with the private subject's subscribe function:
>
> ```
> > const subj = new rx.Subject();
> > const exposed = new rx.Observable(fn => subj.subscribe(fn));
> ```

For more details about subjects' semantics, you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849873/what-are-the-semantics-of-different-rxjs-subjects/34860777#34860777).

Comment: Excellent! Yes, it seems the `.asObservable()` method [exists](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/Subject.js.html#lineNumber98), and [has unit tests](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/test-file/spec-js/Subject-spec.js.html#lineNumber308), but is [not listed in the documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html). Thanks!