# what is 'rxjs/Subject' in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am learning Angular2 by this [official cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-setter).

The below code just appears out of sudden. Why "missionAnnounced$" doesn't have a variable declaration? let missionAnnounced$ = ...
What is the logic of the below code?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class MissionService {
  // Observable string sources
  private missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
  private missionConfirmedSource = new Subject<string>();
  // Observable string streams
  missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();
  // Service message commands
  announceMission(mission: string) {
    this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission);
  }
  confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
    this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

Comment: I realize this is a 2 year-old closed post, but just in case someone else also landed here: the line `missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();` is actually a property (of the MissionService class) declaration & initialization; same as the `missionConfirmed$ ` line and the two private lines above it.

Answer (score 21):

An `Observable` only allows for subscribing, while a `Subject` allows for both publishing and subscribing (a subject *is an* observable). So using a `Subject` allows your service to be used as both a publisher *and* a subscriber.

```
@Component({})
class ComponentOne {
  constructor(private service: MissionService) {}

  onClick() {
    service.announceMission('mission started');
  }
}

@Component({})
class ComponentTwo {
  constructor(private service: MissionService) {
    service.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(mission => console.log(mission))
  }
}

@Component({})
class ComponentThree {
  constructor(private service: MissionService) {
    service.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(mission => console.log(mission))
  }
}
```

Now every one that wants to subscribe to the mission announced event can just subscribe. The `ComponentOne` will be the one emitting the mission announced event.

> Why "missionAnnounced$" doesn't have a variable declaration?

It does. `missionAnnounced$` is the variable name, being assigned the `Subject` in its observable form. Class member variables don't use `let`

> What is the logic of the below code?

Subscribers subscribe to the observables (the `$` variables), while publishers call the `announceMission` and `confirmMission`. All subscribers to `missionAnnounced$` and `missionConfirmed$`, respectively, will receive those events.

Answer (score 4):

To complement the previous answer, you will find ample details in the following SO link : [What are the semantics of different RxJS subjects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849873/what-are-the-semantics-of-different-rxjs-subjects/34860777#34860777)

In short, an Rxjs subject implements both the `Observable`, and the `Observer` interface (see the link for more details about the different flavours and behaviours of subject). The standard subject used here acts as a pipe, and pass through its `Observable` interface all the values it receives on its `Observer` interface. The `asObservable` function call that you see in the code hides the implementation of the `Observer` interface, so you cannot inadvertently use it when you are not supposed too, i.e. you can then only use this subject as you use any regular observable.