# How to return an Observable in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscriber

I have this method inside a `authProvider` provider class:

```
getUser() {
    return this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        return user;
    });
}
```

I would like to subscribe to it in a different class, something like:

```
this.authProvider.getUser().subscribe(user => console.log(user));
```

any ideas how to return an `Observable` inside the `getUser()` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `authState` is already Observable. Just return your `authState` and subscribe within another function. In the function for any other work you can use **[RxJS#map](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map)** function.

```
getUser() : Observable {
    return this.afAuth.authState.map(...);
}

....

login() {
   getUser().subscribe(user => {
       return user;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't subscribe inside the `getUser` function. Just return the obsevable.

```
getUser() {
    return this.afAuth.authState
}
```

Comment: makes sense. but, for the sake of the question.. how would I return an `Observable`

Comment: I'm confused. isn't `this.afAuth.authState` returning an observable ??

Comment: if you want to change the return type of `getUser` function to observable then change it like `getUser(): Observable<String>`

Comment: `authState` is an observable, yes.. but, suppose I want to consume it in there, and then return some other, new `Observable`

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this. Then in your component, the one which is calling this function, you can subscribe to this observable.

```
getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create( (observer: Observer<string>) => {
     this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        observer.next(user);
    }, (err) => observer.error("error"));
}); 
}
```

Ashley

Comment: You can also use [`Subjects`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849873/what-are-the-semantics-of-different-rxjs-subjects/34860777#34860777)...

Comment: create is deprecated, use new Observable() instead : 
`getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable( (observer: Observer<string>) => {
     this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        observer.next(user);
    }, (err) => observer.error("error"));
}); 
}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set return type as observable

```
getUser(): Observable<Type> {
    return this.afAuth.authState;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the function directly and subscribe to it in another class.

```
  getUser() {
        return this.afAuth.authState();
  }
```

You can think of observables as functions that are called by subscribing.

```
this.authProvider.getUser().subscribe(user => console.log(user));
```