# rxjs map operator evaluated for each subscriber

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Why is the map operator evaluated for each subscriber instead of once?

```
const obs1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(1).map((x, i) => {
  console.log(i+1 + ':1 map')
  return 'obs1';
})

const obs2 = Rx.Observable.interval(1300).take(1).map((x, i) => {
  console.log(i+1 + ':2 map')
  return 'obs2';
})

const obs3 = Rx.Observable.interval(1700).take(2).map((x, i) => {
  console.log(i+1 + ':3 map')
  return 'obs3';
})

const view = obs1.combineLatest(obs2, obs3, (obs1, obs2, obs3) => {                 return obs1 + ', ' + obs2 + ', ' + obs3; });

// Every subscriber adds more calls to map - why is it called multiple     times at the same time ?

view.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log('sub1: ' + value)
});

view.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log('sub2: ' + value)
});

view.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log('sub3: ' + value)
});
```

I created a testcase here: http://jsbin.com/jubinuf/3/edit?js,console

Can I write this testcase differently to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kyle answer is correct. `publish().refCount()` applied to all three observables will result in the `map` selector function not being reexecuted.

To elaborate a bit more on that answer, it is useful to understand the difference between hot and cold observables when you use Rxjs. In your case, all your observables `obsX` are cold, so they are 'restarted' on subscription. `combineLatest` subscribes under the hood to all 3, which is why `map` is reexecuted. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators/34669444#34669444) for an illustrated explanation. It is a common stumbling block for beginners but it is quite simple to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Every subscriber will run through the Observable sequence. If you want everyone to get the resulting stream instead, use [`.publish().refCount()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/refcount.md).

http://jsbin.com/ditikonopi/edit?js,console

The [`.publish()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/publish.md) will return an observable sequence that shares a single subscription to the underlying sequence. [`refCount()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/refcount.md) will stay connected to the source so long as there is at least one subscription.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/should-accepted-answers-on-old-questions-be-edited-to-reflect-the-best-answer