# Nativescript 3 w/ Angular 4.1.3 observer not returning filter results

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am having an issue where I can't get an observer to return the filtered set I have running within it.  I copied this from the Giftler(https://www.nativescript.org/blog/merry-and-bright-create-a-mobile-app-with-firebase-angular-2-and-nativescript) example completely end to end and it works on there, but seemingly not for me..

Here's my code that is relevant to the issue

This is the array information

```
beers: BehaviorSubject<Array<Beer>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
private _allBeers: Array<Beer> = [];
```

This is my function for getting local beer information (using firebase initially to load data in array)

```
getLocalBeerDetail(id: string): Observable<any> {

    return new Observable((observer: any) => {

        observer.next(
            this._allBeers.filter(s => s.id === id)[0]
        );
        console.log("Here is the local query status of allBeers array: " + this._allBeers);

    }).share();

}
```

Here is the function that calls the above function and does the subscribing.

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {

        this.id = params['id'];

        this.firebaseService.getLocalBeerDetail(this.id).subscribe((beer) => {

            console.log("Here is the status of beer observable: " + beer);

            this.ngZone.run(() => {

                for (let prop in beer) {

                    if (prop === "id") {
                        this.id = beer[prop];
                        console.log("Here is the detail id:" + this.id);
                    }

                    if (prop === "name") {
                        this.name = beer[prop];
                        console.log("Here is the detail id:" + this.name);
                    }

                }

            });

        });

    });

}
```

Not sure what the issue is but this should be working, based on using the Giftler example.

Comment: Are you sure you subscribed to that observable somewhere?
The observable is "cold" if there is no subscriber to it. Take a look here to see the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698876/2727080

Comment: Sorry I meant to add this here's the detail view that calls the getLocalBeerDetail observable.  I've added it above.