# Observable returned by Http fired each time async pipe is subscribing

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have this method that returns some observable.

```
fetch(publication: Publication): Observable<Array<ProcessingCenter>> {
  return this.http.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/publications/${publication.id}`, {
    headers: headers
  }).map(response => {
    return response.json() as Array<ProcessingCenter>;
  })
}
```

I store returned value (`getObservable` always returns the same observable).

And in one component I utilize this observable in component:

```
<tr *ngFor="let pc of getObservable(p) | async">
  ...
</tr>
```

And now, even though I'm always using the same observable, when I toggle component, each time it is created and async pipe is subscribing, an AJAX request is issued. AFAIK AJAX request should be issued only once, when first subscription is done, right?

### EDIT

Thanks for answers, but they just don't focus on the real issue. Let's me rephrase it.

1. Suppose I have a observable variable `myObservable` returned by `Http` service
2. Suppose in template I'm using this variable with `async` pipe
3. Suppose that I'm toggling a part of the template that is using `async` pipe with simple `*ngIf`

E.g.:

```
<button (click)="toggle = !toggle">Toggle</button>
<table class="table table-condensed" *ngIf="toggle">
  <!-- Somewhere in here is myObservable | async  -->>
</table>
```

Now, when I click the button, each time table is toggled, http request is sent (even though `myObservable` is still the same observable object (component's instance field).

And the questions is: what is so special about `async` pipe or observable that is returned by `Http` service that makes them do `Http` request each time a subscription is made?

Comment: when ever you toggle between components the component is created again   that is the default behaviour of an angular app , you can change this by using canReuse so that component is not destroyed or  recreated again and again, you can check this placing the lifecycle hook ngOnDestroy on the comp

Comment: But I don't mind creating/destroying the component. I'm just curious why each time pipe is subscribing to observable, it it executed.

Comment: because i guess in your component constructor or ngOnInit you might be calling this method right so this will in turn invoke that pipe

Comment: `fetch` method is called only once, and I reuse `Observable<Array<ProcessingCenter>>`

Comment: sorry mybad the component template is loaded everytime the component is recreated so the pipe is invoked

Comment: I think you will find this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141722/how-does-the-rxjs-5-share-operator-work. I think you just need to use the SHARE operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the normal way observables work. The logic they run in order to produce values (ie firing an http request and waiting for its result) is executed every time an observer subscribes. These are called `cold` observables. You can instead have `hot` observables that execute the logic once, by using `publish()`. If an observer subscribed after such observable emitted its values, it would receive nothing. But you can have other variants of `hot` observables that would know how to deal with already emitted values, at each new subscription. See `publishLast()`, `publishBehavior()` and `publishReplay()`.

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html explains what you wrote. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use publishLast with refcount. publishLast is multicast operator with AsyncSubject that will execute the observable once and remember.

Something like that:

```
rows$ = Observable.of([1, 2, 3]).do(x => 
                   console.log(x)).publishLast().refCount();
```

Answer (score -3):

You do not need to worry about it because, browser understands that you are requesting same resource again, which is already present in cache, so browser add header in request stating, give me content only if its new, So although request is made each time, you get data from server only if its new, otherwise you just get empty response with 304 status.

This repeated request also can be avoided with proper configurations on backend, which states for how much time browser can consider the response to be new by default.

This link explains it https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/worried-making-repeated-requests-same-resource-slowing-akshay-jain/