# .share() with .subscribe() _isScalar is missing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, rxjs, ionic3

I am trying to use `share()` with `subscribe()` but got error message as follow. Initially, i started with subscribe. How can this be fix?

My intention is to execute the logic in subscribe. Share is needed to prevent multiple call with async pipe.

> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>   Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'. (property)
>   PostDetailPage.post: Observable

```
 this.post = this.data.getPostById(this.postId).share().subscribe(data => {
          this.post = data;
      },
      err => {
          console.log("Oops!");
      })
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.subscribe()` returns a `Subscription` (allows to unsubscribe).
If you want an `Observable`, don't use `subscribe(...)`.
You can instead use `map(...)`

```
  this.post = this.data.getPostById(this.postId).share().map(data => {
      this.post = data;
  })
```

Comment: You can use the `catch` (for the onError parameter) and `finally` (for onCompletion) operators instead. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/catch.ts

Comment: just a sideline can u explain in which scenario should i use subscribe vs share. Because some say use subscribe some say use share with async pipe to prevent manual unsubscribe and multiple call. I am pretty confused on which is a better approach/practice.

Comment: Subscribe and share aren't interchangeable in any way. Subscribe is actually executing the executable. Without subscribe, you won't get any values. There are alternative operators like `forEach` that also execute the observable, but `share` doesn't, `share` just changes the behavior when subscribe is called multiple times on the same observable. (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141722/how-does-the-rxjs-5-share-operator-work)

Comment: Delegating the subscription/unsubscription to the `| async` pipe is usually a good idea. It also causes change detection to run every time a new value is emitted. If you need to add some filter, map, ... or other operator, you can still assign the result to a field (like the code in my answer or your question) and use this with `| async`.