# Lasest combination of derived streams

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have 3 streams, one say main stream s1, and two derived streams. I want to get latest combination of this streams.

```
const O = Rx.Observable

let s1$ = O.from([1,2,3])
let s2$ = s1$.map(x => x*10)
let s3$ = s1$.map(x => x*100)

let s$ = O.combineLatest(s1$, s2$, s3$, (s1, s2, s3) => {
  //console.log('s1, s2', s1, s2, s3)  
  return s1 + s2 + s3
})

s$.subscribe(x => {
  console.log('s = ' + x)
})
```

The output is:

```
"s = 111"
"s = 112"
"s = 122"
"s = 222"
"s = 223"
"s = 233"
"s = 333"
```

But what I want is:

```
"s = 111"
"s = 222"
"s = 333"
```

So only last and form s1 and its derived values from s2 and s3. What is the best way to achieve it?

A fiddle:
https://jsbin.com/haduvedule/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `share` the s1$ observable. i.e. your code becomes :

```
console.clear()
const O = Rx.Observable

let s1$ = O.from([1,2,3]).share()
let s2$ = s1$.map(x => x*10).delay(10000)
let s3$ = s1$.map(x => x*100)

let s$ = O.zip(s1$, s2$, s3$, (s1, s2, s3) => {
  //console.log('s1, s2', s1, s2, s3)  
  return s1 + s2 + s3
})

s$.subscribe(x => {
  console.log('s = ' + x)
})
```

Why is that has been extensively discussed on SO, I encourage to have a look at the distinction between [hot and cold observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators/34669444#34669444.). It is a key concept of Rx and a common stumbling block for new comers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for me it is still a question when I need to use `.share()`, can you explain in general case is there some rule?

Comment: Follow the link, there are some illustration of the subscription and the data flows.