# RxJS - How to use toArray() with an array of asynchronous observables?

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm creating an array of asynchronous observables with `Rx.Observable.create()` and hope to use `.toArray()` to get all the values when they complete.

```
console.log('running');
let valsArray = ['a','b','c'].map((val,i)=>{
  return Rx.Observable.create((obs)=>{
    let tid = setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(val + ' timing out');
      obs.onNext(val);
    },i*500);
    return ()=>{
      clearTimeout(tid);
    };
  }).publish().refCount();
});

Rx.Observable.from(valsArray)
.flatMap((v)=>v)
.toArray()
.subscribe((arr)=>{
  console.log("arr should be ['a','b','c']",arr);
});
```

Above example at http://jsbin.com/wegoha/10/edit?js,console.

Using `setTimeout` as a stand-in for other asynchronous operations to keep the example simple.

Comment: You shouldn't link to external site unless it supports the information already in your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is correct except you didn't complete the source observables.

The `toArray()` operator can only work when the observable completes, and since you didn't complete the `Rx.Observable.create` then your query could never end.

Try this:

```
console.log('running');
let valsArray = ['a','b','c'].map((val,i)=>{
  return Rx.Observable.create((obs)=>{
    let tid = setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(val + ' timing out');
      obs.onNext(val);
      obs.onCompleted();
    },i*500);
    return ()=>{
      clearTimeout(tid);
    };
  }).publish().refCount();
});

Rx.Observable.from(valsArray)
.flatMap((v)=>v)
.toArray()
.subscribe((arr)=>{
  console.log("arr should be ['a','b','c']",arr);
});
```

Also, just as a side-note, the `.publish().refCount()` seems wrong here. There's no need in this code to make the source observables hot.

Comment: Thank you.  Worked like a charm, and now I understand the onCompleted method better.  Also checked out the hot and cold observables docs again since I didn't fully understand them.  Fantastic description at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators