# Difference between Cold observable and Replay subject?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I can see from the docs that:

Cold Observables emit the entire sequence of values from the start to every Observer.

and

ReplaySubject emits to any observer all of the items that were emitted by the source Observable(s), regardless of when the observer subscribes.

So what is the difference between these two concepts?

Thanks

Comment: Please watch this one https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-demystifying-cold-and-hot-observables-in-rxjs or this video https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/J.Van.Gogh/Rx-API-in-depth-Hot-and-Cold-observables

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once the `ReplaySubject` subscribes to the source observable, the source begins emitting, and the `ReplaySubject` becomes a hot observable. From a subscriber standpoint, subscribing the the `ReplaySubject` it may not be obvious, as it gets all the previously emitted values. But the `ReplaySubject` only subscribes to the source once, so the only way for the subject to be able to re-emit those source values to later subscribers, is to cache those values.

So the difference would be that when subscribing straight to the source observable, the source re-emits the values for each subscriber, whereas with the `ReplaySubject` subscribing to the source, the source only emits once, and any subscriber to the subject, gets those cached values.

Consider the following source observable

```
var source = Rx.Observable.create(function(subscriber) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    subscriber.onNext(i);
    console.log("onNext: " + i);
  }
  subscriber.onCompleted();
});
```

If we subscribe directly to the source, we should see the set of logs twice

```
source.subscribe(function(value) {});
source.subscribe(function(value) {});
//onNext: 0
//onNext: 1
//onNext: 0
//onNext: 1
```

With the `ReplaySubject`, once it subscribes to the source, the source begins emitting, causing the hot subject to begin emitting and caching the values.

```
var subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
source.subscribe(subject);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('subscribe subject');
  subject.subscribe(function(value) { console.log('subscriber')});
  subject.subscribe(function(value) { console.log('subscriber')});
}, 100);
//onNext: 0
//onNext: 1
//subscribe subject
//subscriber
//subscriber
//subscriber
//subscriber
```

Here, you see the source begins emitting once it is subscribed to by the subject.  But any subscriptions to the subject, doesn't cause the source to re-emit, as with the previous example where each new subscriber causes the source to re-emit.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate further on the previous answer, I would recommend you to have a look at another SO question which should help make things more clear : [Hot and Cold observables : are there 'hot' and 'cold' operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators/34669444#34669444)

Yes, if we talk about a `replay()`, i.e. without any arguments, the behaviour of a replay and a cold observable look similar. However, they are not the same.

For instance,

```
cold$ = Rx.Observable.just(1).map(function(){return Math.random();});
coldReplay$ = cold$.replay();
cold$.subscribe(function(x){console.log('cold:' + x);})
cold$.subscribe(function(x){console.log('cold:' + x);})
coldReplay$.subscribe(function(x){console.log('replay:' + x);});
coldReplay$.subscribe(function(x){console.log('replay:' + x);});
```

will never give you the same values when you subscribe to the replay and when you subscribe directly the cold observable.

Why is that should be clear from the link aforementioned. When you subscribe to a cold observable, you start from the first source down to the subscription. When you replay, you don't restart, the replay has kept in a buffer the values that were emitted, and pass directly immediately those values from the buffer and the new ones.