# subscribe method is not triggered with RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm quite a beginner in RxJS,
I'm currently using RxJS@5 and don't understand a behavior of my code

```
const currentExtentMinutes$ = initialExtentMinutes$
    .merge(selectedExtentMinutes$)
    .distinctUntilChanged()

// We message the worker that
// there is a new extent minutes
currentExtentMinutes$
  .subscribe(currentExtentMinutes => {
      console.log('send current extent', currentExtentMinutes);
      currentExtentMinutes => worker.postMessage({currentExtentMinutes});
  });
```

This works great, but as soon as I add this other piece of code, the first subscribe doesn't work anymore

```
sortedTeams$.withLatestFrom(currentExtentMinutes$)
  .subscribe(([teams, extent]) => {
      const d3line = line()
        .x((pt, i) => scaleMinutes.invert(extent[0]) + scaleMinutes.invert(i))
        .y(scaleRanking)
        .curve(curveCardinal.tension(.5));
      const lines = gGraph.selectAll('.team-path').data(teams, _.get('name'));
      lines.enter().append('path')
        .attr('class', 'team-path')
        .style('stroke', team => `rgb(${team.colors[0]})`)
        .style('stroke-width', 7)
        .style('stroke-linecap', 'round')
        .style('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .merge(lines)
        .transition(t)
        .attr('d', team => d3line(team.ranking));
  });
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be yet another victim of the hot vs. cold nature of observables. Basically `currentExtentMinutes` is subscribed twice, once in the first code snippet, and the second time with the use of `withLatestFrom`. Every subscription to a cold observable will restart the producer, producing values anew (for more details have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators/34669444#34669444)).

If that is the problem here, then it should be enough to 'share' your cold observable with

```
const currentExtentMinutes$ = initialExtentMinutes$
    .merge(selectedExtentMinutes$)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .share()
```

Comment: Ha yes indeed! I was pretty sure that it was not a very smart question... Thanks for replying so fast!

Comment: Your challenge will be having only one subscription at the end, in an observable chain.