# Why is Node RxJS .subscribe() not being triggered with bindNodeCallback()?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, observers

I'm learning how to use RxJS with Node. Looking at examples ([1](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindNodeCallback), [2 (old)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442676/how-to-prevent-node-js-from-exiting-while-waiting-for-a-callback), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328361/rxjs-subscribe-method-being-ignored)), I'm so far unable to trigger the 'results' or 'err' methods in .subscribe():

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { bindNodeCallback } = require('rxjs');

const configPath = './config/config.yml';
const configEncoding = 'utf8';

// also tried with bindCallback()...
const readFileSync = bindNodeCallback(fs.readFileSync);

readFileSync(configPath, configEncoding)
.subscribe(
  results => console.log(results), 
  err => console.error(err)
);

// temporary, exits immediately otherwise
// hmmm clue to the above not being correct?...
setInterval(() => { let keep = 'going'; }, 1000);
```

I'm using `"rxjs": "^6.4.0"`, node v10.14.2.

How may I alter this code so that my observer observes the config file loading?

Comment: Posting questions in itself sometimes helps answer a question. If I use `fs.readFile` instead of `fs.readFileSync`, all works well. Please help me explain why this is the case as an answer?

Comment: You may find this article interesting https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxjs-and-node-8f4e0acebc7c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use readFile instead of readFileSync besause readFileSync does not work with a callback.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options