# Merged observable does not contain sequence even though mergees do

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I've got a function that essentially takes a DOM element, looks for some identifying stuff, and (in theory) returns an `Observable` that contains the aforementioned identifying stuff `withLatestFrom`ed with some other stuff.

My problem is that the returned `Observable` doesn't emit any whatchamacallits, even though the `primaries$` and `highlights$` observables that it's made from do.

I'm terribly sorry if this is poorly explained, I'm new to ReactiveX/RxJS and I'm doing my best; if you need further information, ask.

```
function randomFunction(element) {
  // Create an observable sequence of text nodes from an array
  const textNodes$ = Rx.Observable.from(getAllTextNodesFrom(element))

  // Get "highlights" by doing stuff with text nodes
  const highlights$ = textNodes$
    .map(doSomeStuff)
    .zip(textNodes$, (res, node) => ({res, node}))
    .filter(({res, node}) => res.length && node.isConnected)

  // Get "primaries" by doing stuff with "highlights"
  const primaries$ = highlights$
    .map(x => x.res)
    .flatMap(x => x.filter(y => y.matches && y.isPrimary))
    .map(x => x.id)
    .toSet()

  // Create return observable from highlights and primaries
  const ret$ = highlights$.withLatestFrom(primaries$)

  // These work
  primaries$.subscribe(x => { console.log("primaries:", x) })
  highlights$.subscribe(x => { console.log("highlights:", x) })

  // This gives me nothing
  ret$.subscribe(x => { console.log("return:", x) })

  return ret$
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on what user3743222 said in their answer, turns out I also needed to pause/buffer `highlights$` when creating `ret$`, and wait for `primaries$` to emit something before continuing. Here's how I did that using `Rx.Observable.prototype.pausableBuffered`

```
function randomFunction(element) {
  // Create an observable sequence of text nodes from an array
  const textNodes$ = Rx.Observable.from(getAllTextNodesFrom(element))

  // Get "highlights" by doing stuff with text nodes
  const highlights$ = textNodes$
    .map(doSomeStuff)
    .zip(textNodes$, (res, node) => ({res, node}))
    .filter(({res, node}) => res.length && node.isConnected)
    .share()
    .tap(console.log.bind(console, 'highlights:'))

  // Get "primaries" by doing stuff with "highlights"
  const primaries$ = highlights$
    .map(x => x.res)
    .flatMap(x => x.filter(y => y.matches && y.isPrimary))
    .map(x => x.id)
    .toSet()
    .tap(console.log.bind(console, 'primaries:'))

  // Observable that outputs true when primaries$ outputs anything
  const primariesExist$ = primaries$.map(() => true)

  // Create return observable from highlights and primaries
  return highlights$
    .pausableBuffered(primariesExist$)
    .withLatestFrom(primaries$)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I observe that you are using some observables twice, in which case you probably should `share` those common source observable. For example, `highlights$` will be subscribed twice, once while producing values for `ret` and once while producing values for `primaries`.

In addition to that, you can put your logging using the `do` or `tap` operator which will perform the logging side-effect without affecting the stream. You do need one `subscribe` to kick off the dataflow. When you subscribe to `ret`, it will subscribe to `highlight` and `primaries` and go up the chain of subscriptions.

Final words, multiple subscriptions are tricky in Rxjs. You need to be aware of the hot vs. cold dichotomy to understand what happens. You can find a detailed examination of the innerworkings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators/34669444#34669444).

So something like :

```
function randomFunction(element) {
  // Create an observable sequence of text nodes from an array
  const textNodes$ = Rx.Observable.from(getAllTextNodesFrom(element))

  // Get "highlights" by doing stuff with text nodes
  const highlights$ = textNodes$
    .map(doSomeStuff)
    .zip(textNodes$, (res, node) => ({res, node}))
    .filter(({res, node}) => res.length && node.isConnected)
    .share()
    .tap(console.log.bind(console, 'highlights:'))

  // Get "primaries" by doing stuff with "highlights"
  const primaries$ = highlights$
    .map(x => x.res)
    .flatMap(x => x.filter(y => y.matches && y.isPrimary))
    .map(x => x.id)
    .toSet()
    .tap(console.log.bind(console, 'primaries:'))

  // Create return observable from highlights and primaries
  const ret$ = highlights$.withLatestFrom(primaries$)

  // These work
  ret$.subscribe(x => { console.log("return:", x) })

  return ret$
}
```