# Why Rx.Observable.of(true) starts to emit

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have following code:

```js
console.log('start');

//emit value every second
const message = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
//emit value as soon as subscribed
const trueObs = () => Rx.Observable.of(true);
// start emitting delayed values as soon as trueObs emits
const delayWhenExample = message.delayWhen(trueObs);
//log values start logging after one second
//ex. output: 0...1...2...3
const subscribe = delayWhenExample.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.8/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Why `Rx.Observable.of(true)` starts to emit value without `subscribe` the observable?
I understand the concept to RxJS as lazy evaluation, it does not emit values, until I am asking it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You are calling `subscribe` on the last line.

Comment: But I do subscribe on `message` observable not on `delayForFiveSeconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `delayWhenExample` is actually a `SubscriptionDelayObservable` observable, which was created by calling `delayWhen()`. It keeps track of the original `message` observable and the observable that you passed to it as an argument (delayForFiveSeconds). When you call `subscribe()`, it will also subscribe behind the scenes to both of these observables, which it needs to calculate its values.

This is really the whole idea of lazy evaluation. You subscribe to the observable that you need, and all of the other observables that it depends on will be subscribed to automatically - but only when necessary. Unsubscribing is also done automatically, which is very convenient when combining data from a lot of different sources.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with Rxjs v5 but here is probably what is happening :

- you subscribe to `delayByExample`, which is `message.delayWhen(delayForFiveSeconds)`
- this in turns leads to subscription to `delayForFiveSeconds` as probably the `delayWhen` operator subscribes to both its operands i.e. `delayWhen(message, delayForFiveSeconds)` leads to subscription to both `message` and `delayForFiveSeconds` and then the value read from `message` is passed forward when a value from `delayForFiveSeconds` is received. But both subscriptions occurs at the time of subscription to `delayWhen`.
- last thing is that `Rx.Observable.of(true)` will emit synchronously on subscription
- so, `delayWhenExample.subscribe(val => console.log(val))` will immediately trigger the emission of `true`

If you want to understand more precisely the chain of subscription taking place, you can refer to the following SO answer which comes with illustrated dataflows :

- [Hot and Cold observables : are there 'hot' and 'cold' operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators/34669444#34669444)