# How to mimic a "callback with promise" function parameter in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I'm an absolute rxjs beginner. For me to start learning to think in observables, I need to translate concepts through code examples. I feel like if I can see the code for this, I can start to do this on my own with other concepts.

I do **NOT** want to CONVERT a promise to an observable, I want to make a new implementation using Observable that can behave *like* a promise. How would I re-write the following using Observables?

```
 constructor(){
    let makeMessage2 = function(){
        return new Promise(resolve, reject){
           setTimeout(()=>{
                  var r = Math.random();
                  resolve("message two plus random value: " + r );
           }, 1000);
        }
    }
    this.logMessageAndResultOfCallback("message one!", makeMessage2);
}
private sideEffect1:string = "";
private sideEffect2:string = "";

logMessageAndResultOfCallback( message1:string, callback:Function ){
    console.log(message1);
    this.sideEffect1 = message1;

    callback().then((message2)=>{
          console.log(message2);
          this.sideEffect2 = message2;
    }
}
```

I guess the part I don't understand is how to define the "callback" function, how to invoke it. I understand I would wait for the complete or emit handlers, like `makeMessage2().subscribe(message2 => console.log(message2));` but I don't have any clue how to define `makeMessage2`.

This may be totally clueless question, but I've read about 10 different intros to rxjs and this hasn't quite clicked. I just need to map this scenario to observable pattern and I think I can understand it.

Basically, I want to define an observable function `myObs()` that does not "execute immediately" but "executes" whenever the `someMethod(message:string,obs:Observable)` is executed. When `myObs` is executed, it should do something ansynchronously within it (like get the result of a HTTP request) then set the next value, then fire a complete() so my observer defined in `someMethod` can handle the complete and do something with the result.

**Edit:** I'm not concerned with the timer or native equivalents in rxjs, this is just to simulate any async action, like getting data from the server.

Comment: `Observable.create` takes subscriber function -- that executes to whoever subscribes. Dose this not work for you? Your question is not really clear. On rxjs docs site there is a good wizard on how to start observable from different things

Comment: "promise callback pattern" also very confusion.. usually those are 2 different approach for async code

Comment: So, I ended up doing my own attempt. Does this seem correct?

Comment: Exactly, it's potentially two async behaviors. In my use case, it is dismissing a UI item after the "callback" is done computing, but does not call the callback until user action.

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant. Just fyi though for this example thing though you don't need setTimeout at all, there is build in rx operator `delayTime`

Comment: that's just to simulate some async action, like getting something from the server or etc. I'm not actually concerned with timers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with help from [this](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html) guide.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
var makeMessage2 = Observable.create(observer => {
  // Yield a single value and complete
  setTimeout(function(){
     let r = Math.random();
     observer.next("message two plus random value: " + r );
     observer.complete();
  }, 1000);
  return () => console.log('disposed')
});
logMessageAndResultOfCallback( "some message one", makeMessage2);


logMessageAndResultOfCallback( message1:string, callback:Observeable ){
    console.log(message1);
    this.sideEffect1 = message1;

    var subscription = callback.subscribe(
       (value)=>{this.sideEffect2 = value;},
       (e) =>{ console.log('onError: %s', e)},
       () => {console.log(this.sideEffect2);});
      subscription.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you wrote and want to 'translate' to observables probably would not work. `callback` is a promise, not a function, so you can't write `callback()`.

Did you try this [introduction](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) too? It worked for many people.

To answer your question, you could write

```
Rx.Observable.of(""message one!", "message two!")
  .map(console.log.bind(console)) // would be better to use `do` operator actually, for semantic reasons, but that works the same here
  .subscribe(noop, noop, noop)
```

or

```
Rx.Observable.of(""message one!", "message two!")
  .subscribe(console.log.bind(console), noop, noop)
```

where `noop` is a function that does not do anything, i.e. `function noop(){}`

In short, your stream emits data, that data flow through a series of operators, and the data flow is started by `.subscribe`. In your case, you have nothing interesting to do on subscription, because all you do is logging.

Rxjs Streams are in fact callback-based under the hood. You want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators/34669444#34669444) to understand it.

Comment: Oops, meant to make a function that returns a promise. Edited code. I don't think this is what I'm looking for. The intended use case is a function that has some initial side effect (logs message1), and requires a "callback" to be invoked with an asynchronous resolution. The resolution of that callback needs to invoke behaviors/side effects  that are agnostic to the callback functions internals. I'm not simply trying to print two messages.

Comment: No, I need side effects. your example can't do this. I just made my example have concrete side effects for illustration.

Comment: I added my attempt. does this seem to match the pattern I propose?