# Can I create a brand new stream from the existing stream in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

For Example, I have a stream a number of numbers say 1,2,3,4 and so on. I want to sense each of these data and whenever it's even I want to emit true in another data stream. keeping the source data stram[1,2,3,4] as is.

Comment: Your question lacks of information and not clear at all.

Comment: Of course you can

Comment: @noririco, For Example, I have a  stream a number of numbers say 1,2,3,4 and so on and I want to emit new data whenever it's even keeping the source data stram[1,2,3,4] as it is.

Comment: I got to know that I can do it with the help of another SubjectObservable. tap on each emitted data from source stream and check the condition and based on that subject will emit new data.

Comment: You question is a bit unclear, but in my opinion you should read about the differences between cold and hot Observables, you read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521277/what-are-the-hot-and-cold-observables#:~:text=Hot%20observables%20are%20ones%20that,over%20if%20you%20subscribe%20again.)

Comment: I tried to implement like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-playground-jnvvle

Comment: @ohana ive added more details. I hope its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to share your source and subscribe to it twice.

```js
  ...

  private source$ = of(1,2,3,4,5,6).pipe(share());
  
  private evenNumberObservable$ = this.source$.pipe(
    map(x => x % 2 === 0),
    filter(x => !!x)
  );

  //or
  //private evenNumberObservable$ = this.source$.pipe(
  //  filter(x => x % 2 === 0),
  //  map(x => true)
  //);

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.evenNumberObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    this.source$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
  }

  ...
```

whole [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-playground-2tydac)