# Why reactor does not process each element concurrently?

Tags: java, rx-java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

What I expect is reactor will create threads for each emitted element, meaning elements `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` from the source should be handled concurrently. But it's not true from my demo code output, but I don't know why. Could someone take a look and explain to me for two things:

1. Why does reactor in my demo code handles elements in **synchronize** fashion？
2. How to make reactor handles each element **concurrent**?

Though the reactor chain in my below demo code is async to the main thread, each element from source `flux` emits in a synchronized way.

Here is my demo code

```
        System.out.println("main thread start ...");

        Flux.range(1,5)
                .flatMap(num->{
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return Mono.just(num);
                }).flatMap(num-> Mono.just(num*10) )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .subscribe(res-> System.out.println("Thread name:" + Thread.currentThread().getName()+" value:" + res));


        System.out.println("main thread sleep a little");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        System.out.println("main thread end ...");
```

Here is the **output**

```
        Output:
            main thread start ...
            main thread sleep a little
            0. element: 0
            1. element: 1
            main thread end ...
            2. element: 2
```

Comment: Threads are not free. Why do you expect that it _would_ create a thread per item?

Comment: Hi, @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- , I use this demo as a POC to understand how async and concurrent are being handled in reactor.

Comment: on the contrary one of the goals of reactor is to perform as much work with as little threads as possible

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not really implemented in a reactive way especially for wrapping non-reactive code. Consider slightly reworked example

```
@Test
void concurrent() {
    Flux<Integer> stream = Flux.range(1, 50)
            .flatMap(this::process)
            .flatMap(num -> Mono.just(num * 10));

    StepVerifier.create(stream)
            .expectNextCount(50)
            .verifyComplete();
}

private Mono<Integer> process(int num) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return num;
    })
    .log()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}
```

If you run it, you would see that execution is happening on multiple threads with concurrency of `Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE`

```
22:54:26.066  [boundedElastic-50] INFO [r.M.L.50] - | request(32)
22:54:27.038  [boundedElastic-6] INFO [r.M.L.6] - | onNext(6)
22:54:27.038  [boundedElastic-11] INFO [r.M.L.11] - | onNext(11)
22:54:27.038  [boundedElastic-2] INFO [r.M.L.2] - | onNext(2)
22:54:27.038  [boundedElastic-9] INFO [r.M.L.9] - | onNext(9)
22:54:27.038  [boundedElastic-3] INFO [r.M.L.3] - | onNext(3)
22:54:27.040  [boundedElastic-13] INFO [r.M.L.13] - | onNext(13)
22:54:27.040  [boundedElastic-7] INFO [r.M.L.7] - | onNext(7)
22:54:27.040  [boundedElastic-20] INFO [r.M.L.20] - | onNext(20)
22:54:27.041  [boundedElastic-6] INFO [r.M.L.6] - | onComplete()
22:54:27.041  [boundedElastic-13] INFO [r.M.L.13] - | onComplete()
22:54:27.043  [boundedElastic-2] INFO [r.M.L.2] - | onComplete()
22:54:27.043  [boundedElastic-3] INFO [r.M.L.3] - | onComplete()
22:54:27.043  [boundedElastic-20] INFO [r.M.L.20] - | onComplete()
22:54:27.043  [boundedElastic-11] INFO [r.M.L.11] - | onComplete()
22:54:27.043  [boundedElastic-7] INFO [r.M.L.7] - | onComplete()
22:54:27.044  [boundedElastic-9] INFO [r.M.L.9] - | onComplete()
22:54:27.045  [boundedElastic-1] INFO [r.M.L.1] - | onNext(1)
22:54:27.045  [boundedElastic-5] INFO [r.M.L.5] - | onNext(5)
22:54:27.045  [boundedElastic-15] INFO [r.M.L.15] - | onNext(15)
22:54:27.045  [boundedElastic-1] INFO [r.M.L.1] - | onComplete()
22:54:27.045  [boundedElastic-15] INFO [r.M.L.15] - | onComplete()
```

Also, you could check [Flight of the Flux 3 - Hopping Threads and Schedulers](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers) for more detailed explanation and more examples.

Comment: Thank you @Alex, I'll check the page you shared. I notice the main difference between your and my demo is your code returns a `Mono.fromCallable` and mine returns`Mono.just()`, is this one reason (or the only) reason makes your demo concurrently and mine does not ?

Comment: @LomoY https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521277/what-are-the-hot-and-cold-observables