# What happens when a subscription to RXJava's Single happens after the object has already emitted data?

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to solve a data race issue in my program.
I thought about using RXJava's Single but due to the way the program runs, it's uncertain whether the receiver will be able to subscribe to the Single before it emits data.

I was unable to find information if the Single observable implements something like a retro-emit(?) - I don't know how to call that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on how the `Single` "creates" the data. Cold sources will only emit if they have an observer. Hot Singles (in your area) will remember the item they receive and will replay it to future observers.

Comment: So how can I make sure that I have a Hot Single :) ? In my implementation the Single would be emitting a simple boolean value after certain async operations are finished in one class, then the other class would react to that accordingly.

Comment: For a hot source, you will need to subscribe before the value is emitted. Simple. Alternatively you can buffer the emitted element since there’s only going to be one. [What are the Hot and Cold observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521277/what-are-the-hot-and-cold-observables)